# How to reuse the same datatable for different beans?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Is it possible to use the same datatable with multiple data sources? If yes, then how? Can someone give me an example of it? 
To be more precise, can we bind/unbind different sources to datatable programaticaly?

Comment: You can make your managed bean fetch data from the sources you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sample code is given below for clarity ...

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="myRadio" value="#{beanProductDetails.selectedtype}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.types}"/>
    <f:ajax event="valueChange" update="panel_CATALOG" listener="#{bean.typeChanged}" />
</p:selectOneRadio>


<h:panelGrid id="panel_CATALOG">
    <p:dataTable id="table_Details" value="#{bean.list_Details}">
        ........
    </p:dataTable>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Provide selectOneRadio to decide which data source to use. Here, in typeChanged method of the bean, decide what should be list_Details depending on the selectedtype.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. But can you tell me in one line how can we change the data source of our datatable in typeChanged listner?

Comment: It depends on how you are organizing your data. 1. You may maintain records of all data sources as a single list and decide on specific sublist to be shown in the datatable based on start and end index in the list as per the selectedtype. 2. You may copy the data from a specific source into list_Details based on selectedtype etc. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible. Normally you set the value attribute of your datatable to a `List<MyClass>` where `MyClass` can be a pojo or an entity. The list is an instance variable of your backing bean and of course the variable can change at runtime.

Comment: thanks :-) can you explain a bit more? Actually i want to know how can we do this programatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Composite Component, for more info follow this tutorial

http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/jsf/jsf2/JSF2-Composite-Components.pdf

and sample file exist in this path

http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/code/composite-components.zip